# Grindline showing when creating a PDf from XLSX

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlwings

I have this simple code, that just takes a template and I'm trying to convert it to a pdf.

The code works but the pdf have the excel gridlines

[PDf Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v3ul.jpg)

At the moment i´m using xlwings to create the pdf but i can switch to another library if I need to

```
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:

    wb = app.books.open('Template.xlsx')
    wb.to_pdf('test.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the 'Print Menu' in excel.
2. Find the option called 'Page Setup'
   [See this image to find the 'Page Setup Option'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5pG.png)
3. Then in the 'Page Setup' option go to 'Sheet' tab and then locate the 'Gridline' option.
   ['Sheet Tab' and Gridline option location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N39Bz.png)
4. Simply uncheck the gridline options and you are done. Then try running your macro again.